# Java Android working with InputStream and File

Tags: java, android, file, inputstream

Well, first of all, I'm just learning and don't quite understand what I'm doing.
What I want is to create an Excel file in memory and then it would be possible to send it with ActionBarSherlock's ShareActionProvider to mail for example.

But I got exeption :

```
11-24 18:45:52.112: W/System.err(22073): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Competition.xls: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
```

As I searched for the answer on the web - it's the problem of file being created in the system area which is read-only. But I want to create it in memory.. Somehow. Once again, I don't really understand well how it works - the way I see it - I create .xls file somewhere in the memory. So the explanation would be helpful.

So, here's the code :

```
private void createFileTosend() {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
        File toSend=null;
        try {
            toSend = getFile();
        } catch (WriteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(toSend));


        outputStream = openFileOutput("Competition.xls",
                Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE | Context.MODE_APPEND);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length = 0;
        try {
            while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0){
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            /* ignore */
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        /* ignore */
    } finally {
        try {
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
           /* ignore */
        }
        try {
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
           /* ignore */
        }
    }
}
public File getFile()  throws IOException, WriteException{
    File file=new File("Competition.xls");

    WritableWorkbook  workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file); 
    //then goes creation of Excel 's xls file which is not important for the question
    workbook.write();
    workbook.close(); 

    return file;
}
```

Once again, don't downvote me, please, I'm just learning

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll need to save it to disk before sharing it. You do not have access to some kind of system-wide "memory" where you can just put stuff that other apps can access.

Comment: @KenWolf - actually, that is untrue.  Android supports literal shared memory, and also some ways of passing data structures through Intents.  But generally this would be done by creating a file on the external storage.

Comment: @ChrisStratton interesting, I'll have to look up literal shared memory (there must be some security implications to this?). Basically I couldn't see how an excel file could be created and shared with other apps without writing to disk, but maybe I misunderstand the requirement.

Comment: I agree that what is desirable is writing it to disk - most destination apps wouldn't be able to accept it otherwise.  I was just pointing out that shared memory mappings actually are permitted, and there are additional mechanisms such as serializing objects to pass, or handing off a callback-like content provider, which could theoretically be used between cooperatively developed apps.

Comment: @user2976267 what is the path of file?

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Ass per the error log you post, i guess you didn't read it carefully. IT is saying read only file system. You need to put the above permission **ATLEAST** in your android manifest.

Do this much and see if there is any more error or not

Comment: No, this is not the problem.  You have failed to understand the error message.  The intended target is not the external storage, but (mistakenly) the root directory, which is why it's a read only file system complaint and not a permission complaint.

Comment: 11-24 18:45:52.112: W/System.err(22073): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Competition.xls: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
" open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)" . This is your error. I have put it in quotes for you

Comment: and secondly you are calling the getFile method. and your error is stating that the file does not exist.

Comment: Sorry I didnt include it in my post, but I have that permission in manifest - it's not the case

Comment: Again, this is not the problem which triggers that error message.  The immediate problem is that the code is trying to create a file in the root directory, not on the external storage.  If and only if the code is changed to create the file on the external storage, then this permission would be needed.

Comment: I included that permission just in case because I saw same problem. So. What is the right way of creating this file?

Comment: Please read about creating files on the External Storage.  It has been covered in numerous questions here, and is in the documentation as well.

Comment: well, I've found solution myself.  public File getFile()  throws IOException, WriteException{
     File file=new File(getCacheDir(), "Competition.xls"); //instead of just File file=new File("Competition.xls"); which was trying to get to system area

Answer (score 0):

I have a doubt may be wrong

```
outputStream = openFileOutput("Competition.xls",
            Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE | Context.MODE_APPEND);
```

you are using `Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE` its readable, so how can you access it in write mode later. Is it right?
Check this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/Y5-PUKuIlbk)

Use the http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html to clear your doubt about file creation

Comment: No, this is not the issue.  Please read the explanation already posted.